# How can I deploy a Go app in Heroku where the runner is in a folder/module?

Tags: go, heroku

I have a program with the structure as such:

```
go/src/repo/game
go/src/repo/server
```

and the entry point is within the `server` folder. I'll do `go build repo/server` and then run the executable.

So i'm trying to deploy the app in Heroku, but there isn't any info on how I can tell Heroku exactly what to build - looks like it just does `go build` within the `repo/`. How can I tell Heroku to do `go build repo/server` instead? Thanks everyone :) !!

PS - if I'm using Go's standard library - strconv, net, etc, so I have to add that to go.mod as a dependency? thanks guys :D

Answer (score 0):

There `// +heroku install` is how you do this. See [here](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-go)